# How to change the QA_PROMPT for my own usecase?

Tags: prompt, openai-api, chain, langchain, gpt-4

### [chain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdCGs.png)

### [I was following this description.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CFIa.png)

I can't understand what QA_PROMPT means, and how I can change it to my own usecase.
I checked my Pinecone index but I can't find anything about QA_PROMPT.
What should I do? Please help me.

Comment: please try to add your sample code in readable format here instead of using an external source.

Answer (score 0):

In short, a prompt is the information you provide to the Language Model. This information can be in the form of a simple sentence (for Language Models) or a conversation-like exchange (for Chat Models) consisting of a list of messages.

If you take a look at the example you shared, it's all about guiding the model on how it should respond to the information you give it. This information includes the `context` and the `question`, and it helps the model understand how to proceed. Now, where does this context come from? Well, it's from the vector database you are using consisting of documents where relevant documents are searched based on the given question.

The `QA_PROMPT` you shared allows you to customize how the model behaves to best suit your specific needs. Just write plain instructions in the prompt or change the existing one you shared to change the model behavior. Let's say you want to get the output in `HTML` format instead of `Markdown`. Just change the instruction to give output in HTML or any other thing you want. Or you don't want the model to act as an `AI assistant`, maybe something else? Try to tweak these changes and see how the model responds after that. :D

Give it some time and you will get what's happening :D